# Interview appointment letter

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I just need some clarification regarding the confirmation letter I received, after completing my grandparents' visa application.

First, I completed my grandmother's appointment application. It asked whether she was travelling to the US with a companion. I answered, yes, and added my grandfather's name. They will make the trip together. When I selected her interview time slot, my grandfather was automatically included.

I did go to his account and discovered that his interview is scheduled for the same date and time as hers. I just want to make sure this is okay.

Does he need a separate confirmation letter to take to the interview? He doesn't have one: his name is on my grandma's appointment confirmation.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Kindly edit.

Comment: Two questions: are you able to go into your grandfather's application and downloaded his confirmation letter? Second: a what consulate is the interview scheduled?